# async def on_ready(): SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: discord.py

I was making an discord bot and im new to python and i have looked up but didn't find any answer on how to fix this but i got error from this code

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = command.Bot(command_prefix="<")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

@client.command()
synd def Test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Test successful")

client.run(Token)
```

line with error:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")
```

Error:

```
async def on_ready():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? i am using Python version: pip 19.2.3 (python 3.8)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using python3 and not python2?

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

The print function needs to be intended another 4 spaces to be like:

```
async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is online")
```

Comment: I tried to install asyncio but it still does not work.

Thanks for telling me i didn't see i typed wrong at async

Comment: The error is pretty obvious you need to indent  the print function another 4 spaces. I edited my answer. have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can try use command "python3 file_name.py"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).